# How do you draw a line between two points in google geo chart?

Tags: google-visualization

I want to draw a line between two points (zip codes in this case) on map using googles geochart function. Is that possible? For example, I would like to have a line drawn between zip 07206 and 78746 below:

```
    <html>
  <head>
    <script type='text/javascript' src='https://www.google.com/jsapi'></script>
    <script type='text/javascript'>
        google.load('visualization', '1', { 'packages': ['geochart'] });
        google.setOnLoadCallback(drawMarkersMap);

        function drawMarkersMap() {
            var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
              ['Region', 'Total'],
              ['07206', 500],
              ['78746', 250],
              ['90040', 1000],
            ]);

            var options = {
                sizeAxis: { minValue: 0, maxValue: 100 },
                region: 'US', // United States
                resolution: 'provinces',
                displayMode: 'markers',
                colorAxis: { colors: ['#e7711c', '#4374e0'] } // orange to blue
            };

            var chart = new google.visualization.GeoChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
            chart.draw(data, options);
        };
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="chart_div" style="width: 900px; height: 500px;"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Have you tried anything to date?

Comment: Drawing lines in a GeoChart is not supported.  You could probably use Google Maps to do this.

Comment: The documentation I am finding for drawing lines is all related to Maps as opposed to GeoCharts. I only want line drawings for states rather than the satellite imagery included with maps. I haven't found anything to try related to GeoCharts so I haven't tried much as this point.

Comment: As asgallant says, there is no way to do this with the current API. You can use maps, or try a workaround of some sort (creating custom code to draw a line on the chart or on an overlapping div with some fancy CSS or somesuch).

Answer (score 3):

[VectorWorkz](http://vectorworkz.com/) GeoChart allows you to draw lines between two points, it enables animation for the lines and also you can customize the look and feel of the connection lines. It is briefly illustrated in this [online sample](http://vectorworkz.com/demo/)(Click on "Flight Routes" in the left menu).

Answer (score 0):

I had a need for this just recently.  Fairly simple solution is to draw 0px points (markers) on the map and then do a jQuery loop through the points and create a  element with the x1 / y1 values of the first point, the x2/y2 values of the second point, etc.